# EMACS auto-complete: Error running timer ‘ac-update-greedy’: (wrong-number-of-arguments setq 1)

Tags: debugging, emacs, autocomplete

Upgraded from:
**EMACS 23.4-bin-i386 with auto-complete-1.3.1**, where AC-Mode worked perfect

to

**GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2017-09-17 with auto-complete-1.5.1 on Windows10**

**.emacs** configuration is:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/EMACS/EMACS_Extentions/auto-complete-1.5.1/")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(add-to-list 'ac-user-dictionary-files "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict/org.dict")
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'org-mode)
```

Now I got the following Error:

```
Auto-Complete mode enabled in current buffer
You can run the command ‘auto-complete-mode’ with M-x au-compl- RET
Auto-Complete mode enabled in current buffer
Error running timer ‘ac-update-greedy’: (wrong-number-of-arguments setq 1)[2 times]
auto-complete error: (wrong-number-of-arguments setq 1)
```

Saw already the same problem posted on GIT-HUB:
https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/issues/442 but there is not a solution for it at all.

Would be happy for any suggestions!

Comment: If you read all the way to the bottom of the github discussion at the link you posted, you'll find there's already a solution for the `setq` error you're showing.

Comment: @SteveVinoski as you can see at my .emacs config, **v1.5.1 of auto-complete** is used, where **#424** was included. But, problem still exists. I think, there´s also no old byte code left on my installation. What else could I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few attempts and another EMACS start, a plausible error message appeared, which helped me further. Auto-Completion now probably has a **dependency on popup.el**. After I integrated this, auto-complete works fine again.